# Uploadify http error 500 on Linux

Tags: ubuntu, uploadify

I am getting an http 500 error when using uploadify on Ubuntu.
The server has write permissions on the folder.
Same code works on windows local machine.

You can see the html and the actual error here:
beta DOT my-calendar DOT gr/calendar/upload-photos

Comment: It seems that the server is throwing a HTTP 500 error. You sure that you have set the write permissions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should look at your webserver's log for explanations of the 500 (Internal Server Error) error. On Ubuntu this log can be found at `/var/log/apache2/error.log`.

Comment: There is nothing on the error.log. Actually the 500 error is thrown by the Uploadify itself, I am not sure if it is representative of a server 500 error

Comment: Uhm. Then you should probably contact the authors of Uploadify and seek help from them.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I could see it's Zend Framework's error, not uploadify. It returns 500 even when trying to upload using plain `input type="file"`

Comment: that is not correct. the production site is working with an input type=file with no problem on the same configuration and permissions.

Comment: this is weird, because it gave me 500 when I injected `input type=file` into the page you mentioned in the question

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the Apache / Zend server on the Ubuntu system has been confined with the [AppArmor](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppArmor) mandatory access control mechanism; perhaps the server is not allowed to write files due to the AppArmor policy, even if the standard Unix discretionary access control policy would otherwise allow the file write.

In a root shell, run `aa-status` to see which profiles are loaded, and which programs currently running are confined. Perhaps your Apache is confined, perhaps Zend is confined. (I'm pretty unfamiliar with zend, so if it is an Apache module, just check for Apache. :)

Comment: hmmm, after running aa-status i don't see the httpd apache process nor any zend related stuff. 0 profiles in complaint mode.

Answer (score 0):

In case there was a usage of 3rd party libraries (e.g. GD for image manipulation using PHP) in the method handling the POST on the server side, please make sure that you have appropriate extensions loaded (e.g. `yum install php-gd` for RHEL/CENTOS).

Answer (score 0):

Check with phpinfo() if mod_security is enabled. If so, that's a probable cause, you can disable it in a .htaccess file:

```
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
```